Are there any original heat shield tiles on any of the retired space shuttles that flew to space?
By "original" I mean that they never needed to be replaced during the life of the vehicle. My reasoning is that if NASA had engineered the shuttle optimally, all the tiles would have been designed to fail at roughly the same time, despite their different locations around the vehicle. Then statistically, tile failures should have been fairly random. So, some (if not lots) of tiles could have gotten lucky and survived for many - possibly all - of the missions.
(Atlantis, Endeavor, and Discovery only - not counting Buran.)

Related: https://space.stackexchange.com/q/39971/6944

Optimal engineering would be (marginal cost of failure) / (marginal cost of improvement) ... in log space? ... being constant; that doesn't mean that failure rates should be constant!  It may be (much) cheaper to make certain areas super-reliable than others, which doesn't (always) mean you should (completely) roll-back reliability on the super-reliable areas.  It can mean you can roll back some reliability there and focus more on the expensive areas, but uniform reliability is definitely not implied.

Given that there are tens of thousands of tiles and they needed to be placed and replaced by hand, optimal engineering would be to minimize the number of different types of tile - ideally, there would only be one tile which you could place anywhere on the heat shield, though in practice that probably wasn't possible. Refurbishment was one of the biggest cost drivers in the program and manual work was a big part of it, so you'd want to focus on minimizing that over minimizing upfront cost/weight.

Yes, a whole lot of them. According to Valerie Neal (emphasis added by me):

One of the USA [United Space Alliance] engineers did a rough count and
estimated that about 18,000 original tiles are still on the vehicle [(Space Shuttle Discovery)]
Since there are 24,000 tiles total, this means that 75% of the tiles are original.


So, 72% of the tiles.

No 18,000/24,000=75% @dan04
