How many of the heat shield tiles on Atlantis and Endeavour are original?
Original in this context means heat shield tiles that were never replaced. From my answer to Are there any original heat shield tiles on any of the retired space shuttles that flew to space?, 75% of Discovery’s tiles are original. As well, according to the Columbia Accident Investigation Board, 44% of the tiles on Columbia were original. However, I could not seem to find any reliable information about Endeavour or Atlantis (or Challenger but I doubt that’s even knowable. If someone could find info on that I would be interested in that too).
I did find a Quora answer by someone claiming to work currently at United Space Alliance, although that company has been closed down for 4 years (the answer is newer than that) and a web search for the name turned up no reliable sources about them or any proof that this was their account.
I think it’s reasonable to assume that some tiles are original, but how many?

Related: https://space.stackexchange.com/q/39971/6944

@AustinOverton / Deko why would you assume that? It wasn't tiles that failed on STS-107, it was the wing leading edge.

@OrganicMarble I'm once more going to assert that I am not Deko. According to a quick google search, Deko is a rapper, notably not an SE user, as well as a female Japanese name. To answer your question though, I said that because I assumed (apparently incorrectly) that they would've replaced tiles on the surviving orbiters to avoid a repeat of the incident. However, your comment was actually useful to clear up my mistake. So, thanks.

@AustinOverton wow, the world is full of amazing coincidences. https://i.imgur.com/ZZqFway.png Give him my regards.

@OrganicMarble
My apologies to both of you (Marble + Starship). I got a bit defensive there and lost my temper. Won't happen again!
